# hook_update_N - expose new field to views after module update

Tags: updating, views

I've added new field to existing table with hook_update_N. Now, is it possible to expose this new field to views? I want it to be exposed when module is updated...

Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can use [`hook_views_data_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7):

> Alter table structure.
>
> You can add/edit/remove existing tables defined by hook_views_data().

Comment: From drupal API : This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be auto-loaded. I was asking if this is possible when invoking hook_update_N...

Comment: It's 'possible', by updating the database manually (wouldn't recommend it, and you're own your own finding out the relevant data/columns), but you'll need to implement this hook anyway for the new information to persists. If you don't implement the hook, the next time the caches are cleared your column will disappear from views. Using the API is always the recommended approach anyway, if you try to get around it you're asking for trouble